# Mejorar el tiempo de respuesta de un LEFT JOIN en Mysql

Tags: mysql

(Corrijo la gráfica. La tabla employee_location solo tiene referencia a la localización)

Tengo las siguientes tablas que me permiten obtener la ubicación de un empleado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla **Employee_information** puede o no tener un valor de referencia para el código de la ubicación. Por lo que también debo buscarlo en la tabla **Location**.
El problema lo tengo con la tabla **employee_location**. En ésta está presente el empleado que no está referenciado en **employee_information**, con una excepción puede aparecer múltiples veces en diferentes ciudades. Sin embargo, el informe que debo presentar SÓLO debe mostrar una ciudad por empleado (a petición del usuario).

Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
select coalesce(ei.name_value, l.name)
from employee e 
INNER JOIN status s ON s.employee_id = e.employee_id 
             AND s.date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-10-01' -- Fechas a modo de ejemplo
Left join employee_information ei ON e.employee_id = ei.employee_id
Left join location l on l.location_id = ei.value

Left join (
          select e1.employee_id, min(l1.location) as location
          from employee e1 
          left join employee_location el1 on e.employee_id = el1.employee_id
          left join location l1 on el1.location_id = l1.location_id
          group by employee_id
) as temp_emp ON temp_emp.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

Cómo puedo mejorar esta subconsulta?. No quiero que se busque la información de TODOS los empleados presentes en employee_location ya que es bastante pesada. Es posible usar los empleados de la tabla con alias **e** en lugar de e1, pues estos ya han sido acotados con las fechas de la tabla status. O alguien quizás pueda reconocer otra manera más óptima de realizar lo que requiero.

Hasta ahora no he logrado encontrar una referencia que me permita solucionar esta inquietud.

Esta es sólo una parte de los datos finales que debe contener el reporte.

Sólo por aclarar. Otro equipo de la empresa desarrollo este modelo (y es complicado a veces obtener aclaraciones de ellos) ,yo solo la consulto.

Espero que haya sido claro con la explicación del problema y alguien me pueda dar una mano.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero una cosa, ¿este JOIN: `Left join employee_information ei ON e.employee_id = ei.employee_id` sirve para algo? ¿Podrías decir para qué sirve en tu consulta? Además no entiendo esto que dices: *No quiero que se busque la información de TODOS los empleados presentes en **`employee_location`** ya que es bastante pesada.* ¿Qué es lo que necesitas de esa tabla exactamente? **¿Qué rayos hace la columna `location` en esa tabla, cuando ya existe en la tabla `Location`**? Parece que tienes redundancia de datos, una tabla auxiliar no debería ser tan pesada.

Comment: @A.Cedano Desafortunadamente lo es. Acabo de corregir el gráfico. Dejé una columna extra que no debería estar allí.

Comment: Lo mismo que te dije en mi anterior comentario, te lo digo con la tabla `employee_information`. ¿Por qué si ya tienes el nombre de la localidad en la tabla `location` **lo repites de nuevo en `employee_information`. Los índices a través del id sirven precisamente para no estar repitiendo las columnas de tipo VARCHAR u otras, evitando así la redundancia de datos.

Comment: No soy desarrollador de la base. Se realizaron cambios recientemente y debo corregir los reportes existentes basados en los nuevos datos.

Comment: Bien. De todos modos tú no necesitas para nada usar la tabla `employee_information`. Creo que esa es la tabla que ralentiza todo. Puedes hacer el JOIN usando solo `employee`, `location` y `employee_location`. Si la consulta sigue lenta significa que deberías revisar los índices en `employee` y/o en `location`.

Comment: @A.Cedano al parecer la tupla (employee_id, location_id) puede estar tanto en `employee_information` como en `employee_location`

Comment: @amenadiel entiendo que pueda estar en varias tablas, ese no sería ningún problema si así fuese necesario (eso dependerá de su diseño). Lo que no entiendo (y creo que esa es la causa del problema), **por qué tiene la columna que aparece en la imagen como `name_value` en la tabla `employee_information`** si por los datos que aparecen en ella parece claro que esa columna almacena los mismos datos que la columna `name`  de la tabla `location`. Tampoco entiendo exactamente el sentido de las columnas `field` y `value` en esa ¿tabla? si es que lo es... a mí hasta me da la impresión de que es `view`.

Answer (score 1):

Con los últimos ajustes a tu pregunta, queda obvio que este join en la parte principal de la consulta está de más:

```
Left join location l on l.location_id = ei.value
```

El join a `location` solo lo necesitas dentro de la tabla derivada.

Adicionalmente, dentro de la tabla derivada, no necesitas hacer otra vez consulta con `employee`, ni tampoco necesitas `LEFT JOIN`s.

La consulta quedaría de la forma siguiente:

```
select coalesce(ei.name_value, el.location_name)
from employee e 
INNER JOIN status s ON s.employee_id = e.employee_id 
             AND s.date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-10-01' -- Fechas a modo de ejemplo
Left join employee_information ei ON e.employee_id = ei.employee_id
left join (
  select el.employee_id, min(l.Name) as location_name
    from employee_location el
    join location l on l.location_id = el.location_id
   group by el.employee_id
) el ON el.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

Comment: Yo creo lo contrario, **que `employee_location` no debería tener una columna `location`**. De ser así, ¿qué sentido tendría la tabla `Location`?.  Precisamente por eso esa tabla es tan pesada como él dice porque repite una y otra vez la columna VARCHAR con el nombre del lugar, cuando debería manejarlo solamente con el id y apuntar a la tabla `Location` para obtener el nombre. Hay un claro error de diseño en sus tablas, el problema no es la consulta en sí, sino el diseño.

Comment: @A. Cedano: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo con lo que dices. Su modelo no está normalizado correctamente. El que eso explique que su consulta sea pesada, no lo sé, de hecho no creo. La denormalización de los datos rara vez empeoran el rendimiento. Mas bien, el problema es que tarde o temprano terminas corrompiendo la coherencia de tus datos. Su consulta necesitaba corrección de una forma u otra. Pero en efecto, esa columna no debería estar allí.

Comment: @sstan acabo de corregir la gráfica. No me había dado cuenta de haber dejado ese campo extra. Lo tenía para una explicación aparte.

Comment: Sucede. Hice los ajustes a la respuesta. En realidad, tu consulta ya casi estaba bien. Solo tienes algunos joins adicionales que no necesitas y que puedes eliminar.

Comment: Si a pesar de estos cambios el rendimiento sigue siendo malo, por favor incluye los planes de ejecución también. Tal vez te falte algún índice por allí.

Comment: @sstan mil gracias por la ayuda. Voy a corregir de acuerdo a las observaciones y veo que ocurre con el tiempo de ejecución. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para mí, **omitiría por completo** la columna `name_value` de la tabla `employee_information`. Si `employee_information` tiene la columna "value" llena y consistente, entonces la usas para hacer el join con `location`. Evidentemente tiene que haber un **índice** en `employee_information.value`. Olvídate de `name_value`. Es inconsistente, dernormalizada y ensucia todo.

Además veo que `employee_information.field` tiene valor `Location`. Si este campo puede tener otros valores diferentes a `Location` entonces no debes hacer un join con la tabla completa. Sólo con las tuplas que tengan valor `Location`. Esto además sugiere que debes hacer un **índice** en `field`.

Dices que la ubicación de un empleado puede no estar en `employee_information` y que en cuyo caso puede estar en `employee_location`. No dices si ambas informaciones son mutuamente excluyentes. ¿Puede un usuario estar en ambas tablas?

Como sea, yo obtendía las tuplas `employee_id, location_id` en una subconsulta y luego haría los joins.

También me imagino que no sólo quieres el nombre de la ubicación, puesto que no tendría utilidad si no la asocias con el nombre del empleado. Me permitiré entonces cambiar los campos del SELECT.

```
SELECT e.name, l.name
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN status s ON s.employee_id = e.employee_id AND s.date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-10-01'
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT employee_id, MIN(location_id) as location_id FROM employee_location el1 GROUP BY employee_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT employee_id, value FROM employee_information WHERE field='Location'
) location_employee ON location_employee.employee_id = e.employee_id

LEFT JOIN location l ON l.location_id=location_employee.location_id
```

Nótese que estoy usando `UNION ALL` porque asumo que un mismo empleado no está a la vez en `employee_information` y `employee_location`.

Posiblemente ayudaría un **índice** sobre `employee_location.location_id` o bien un **índice compuesto** sobre esta misma tabla en `employee_id, location_id`.

Asumo que la llave primaria de `employee` es `employee_id`, la llave primaria de `location` es `location_id` y que hay índices tanto en `employee_location.employee_id`  y `employee_information.employee_id`